# can anyone advise on how to get the test coverage for istio/proxy?

Tags: proxy, istio, test-coverage

build_envoy:
export PATH=$(PATH) CC=$(CC) CXX=$(CXX) && 
bazel $(BAZEL_STARTUP_ARGS) build $(BAZEL_BUILD_ARGS) $(BAZEL_CONFIG_REL) @com_googlesource_chromium_v8//:build && 
bazel $(BAZEL_STARTUP_ARGS) build $(BAZEL_BUILD_ARGS) $(BAZEL_CONFIG_REL) //src/envoy:envoy
@env
@echo "begin bazel test"
export PATH=$(PATH) CC=$(CC) CXX=$(CXX) && bazel $(BAZEL_STARTUP_ARGS) test $(BAZEL_BUILD_ARGS) -- $(BAZEL_TEST_TARGETS)
@echo "end bazel test"
@echo "coverage begin"
bazel $(BAZEL_STARTUP_ARGS) coverage -s --instrument_test_targets --experimental_cc_coverage --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main //...
@echo "coverage end"